# I am experiencing issues with my rounded bottom of my Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an horizontal menu, which have a drop down menu on hover:

**The HTML structure is like this:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>

        <li><!-- DropDown-->
            <a href="#">Drop Down</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dd Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lalalal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul><div class="clear"></div>
        </li>

    </ul><div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**I am currently trying to round the bottom-left/right with the following CSS:**

```
#menu ul li ul {
-khtml-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
-khtml-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
}
```

The problem is that the background of my `<li>` is interfering with the rounded borders of the `<ul>` and it looks ugly.

I did a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MLTu/) so you can see the full code

Comment: Who is this guy "stealing code from everyone"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1074944/bhaumik-patel

Comment: You should have flagged his answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom corners of the `li` are showing outside the `ul`, because of the border radius on the `ul` and solid background of the `li`.

One way to fix it: Add the selector `#menu ul ul li:last-child` to your border styles. Use a class name on the last element instead if you want better browser support.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5MLTu/1/

<strike>Another way: Add the style `overflow:hidden` to your current border styles for the `<ul>`.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5MLTu/2/</strike>

Note: The above method only seems to work in Firefox, so don't use it :)

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly. Btw, the second one doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: You're right, it seems to be Firefox only that `overflow:hidden` works, no-go in Chrome.

Comment: I did all that code from scratch (and I am new at coding), did you see any important flaw? (like, I am not sure where to put the list-style, on ul or li?, etc etc) If you find any important mistake/improvement I would be eternally thankfuled with you :D

Comment: I didn't see anything noteworthy. The code could be smaller and a little more "efficient" but the way you have it is fine, really.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to revise my code. I am aware of the lack of efficientness (I did not group them using commas to increase the readability and to make it easier for the people to understand it)